# GWT Change Color of Span Elements of same Class

Tags: html, gwt

This is a newbie question related to GWT. I have HTML as

```
<span class="timex"><span class="NeNum">seven</span> years</span> have passed since she unlaced her <span class="NeOrg">Air</span> <span class="timex">hours</span>
```

I want to change the color of the text which is wrapped between a span element of a specific class. I understand I can do it using CSS, by defining classes in CSS with the same name as the span class. I am trying to achieve it using GWT.

Can someone please point out a way in which I can select all span elements of the same class for example all span elements with class timex and invoke setStyle on them? Using DOM class I can get a list of all span elements, but I will have to check for their classes individually? This might be inefficient.

Any pointers to ways in which I can change the color will be appreciated.

Thanks

Prateek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of DOM manipulation, I currently use the [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) library (a gwt port of jQuery) :

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
...

$("span.timex").css("color", "red");
```

The code above will select all span attached to the DOM and having 'timex' as css class and change the color of the text to red.

Read the [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted) of gwtquery.